# CUDA Texture functions not identified

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

The CUDA 4.2 SDK example project simpleTexture compiles and runs correctly in vs2008 sp1, but when I attempt to add textures to an ongoing CUDA kernel project, some of the necessary functions to create and use the binding are not recognized:

```
1>c:/ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2/C/src/rohan/Rohan-kernel.cu(67): error: identifier "channelDesc" is undefined
1>c:/ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2/C/src/rohan/Rohan-kernel.cu(664): error: identifier "tex2d" is undefined
```

The texture declaration itself seems okay:

```
texture<cuDoubleComplex, cudaTextureType2D, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;
```

I have duplicated all of the `#include`s from `simpleTexture`, include paths look the same, and the ongoing project uses the supplied template project/solution files customized as directed.

Everything was working well before adding the texture bits, what gives?

Comment: Could you upload a more complete picture of the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to compile with the flag `-arch sm_20`